# Fraction in first line of Example overlaps onto Example header

Tags: line-breaking, theorems, ntheorem, examples

I'm writing an example where the question says to find what the Legendre symbol of a few numbers are equal to.  The theorem style I'm using is 'nonumberbreak' as I like to have my examples start on the following line but as there is a large fraction in the first line of the question, there is some overlap onto the Example header.

[image: Legendre Example overlap]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[amsthm]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\clubpenalty=10000 \widowpenalty=10000

\newcommand{\qedhere}{\ifmmode\qed\else\hfill\proofSymbol\fi}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\theoremstyle{nonumberbreak}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
\normalfont
Find $\left(\dfrac{3}{13}\right)$, $\left(\dfrac{5}{13}\right)$ and  $\left(\dfrac{9}{13}\right)$.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way to sort this out or make the gap between 'Example' and the next line a bit wider?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide the code as text and add it to the question above -- a screen shot of the code isn't very useful most times

Comment: Sniped of your MWE as figure is not of big help ... please, send code, that it can be copied i (not retyped).

Comment: It seems that only will help to insert empty line between theorem body and theorem name. Problem disaper, if you instead `\dfrac` use standard `\frac`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An rude solution: insert some line before`ntheorem` body:

```
\documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[amsthm]{ntheorem}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
\clubpenalty=10000 \widowpenalty=10000
\newcommand{\qedhere}{\ifmmode\qed\else\hfill\proofSymbol\fi}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{nonumberbreak}
\theoremseparator{:\newline}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

    \begin{document}
\begin{example}
\mbox{}\\[-2ex]% <---- added
Find $\left(\dfrac{3}{13}\right)$, $\left(\dfrac{5}{13}\right)$ and  $\left(\dfrac{9}{13}\right)$.
\end{example}
    \end{document}
```

[image]